# Are formula (functions) supported in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I have often used `=lorem()` or `=rand()` to generate random text in MS-Word. Are any formula or functions, not necessarily random text generator, supported in Google Docs?

To be more specific, can we insert hyperlink the way we insert in Spreadsheets i.e for instance, `=HYPERLINK(url,text)` is used in Sheets. Can anything can be done in Google Docs for the same?

Kindly note, I am not looking for shortcuts.

Comment: tried what I have mentioned.

Comment: Aren't these two different questions? In any case, would you be open to using Apps Script to accomplish this?

Comment: @lamblichus `Aren't these two different questions?` Yes, answering either is fine. Because I just want to know if there is a way to execute functions as we type. It doesn't matter if it's for lorem or for hyperlink. `would you be open to using Apps Script to accomplish this?` If you are talking about creating add-on, I am open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the **random text generator** I remember there was an add-on to generate *lorem ipsum* but it was not in-built like MS-Word's `=lorem()`.

Regarding the formula, it can't be done unfortunately as of now in Google Docs.

Similar question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74855/perform-basic-maths-on-contents-of-google-document-not-spreadsheet